# a problem on solving a determinant equation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $a$ be a real number. What is the number of distinct real roots of the following

$$\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
x & a & a & a \\
a & x & a & a \\
a & a & x & a \\
a & a & a & x \end{array} \right|=0.$$

I guess some method is there other than calculating the determinant explicitly.

Comment: @Amzoti If you read the solution, it has the eigenvalues as well. Also, given the eigenvalues, you can find the determinant trivially.

Comment: @user17762 but wouldn't determining the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A involve the same time-consuming process of calculating the determinant.

Comment: @JohnathonSvenkat There is no time-consuming process. All the things eigenvalues, determinant, eigenvectors etc are trivial in this case, if you read the duplicate post.

Comment: See also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84206/how-to-calculate-the-following-determinants-all-ones-minus-i/

Answer (score 2):

I assume $a\neq 0$, for otherwise the question is trivial.

Note this is the characteristic polynomial 
$$
p_A(x)=\det(xI_4-A)
$$
of the real symmetric matrix
$$A=\pmatrix{0&-a&-a&-a\\ -a&0&-a&-a\\-a&-a&0&-a\\-a&-a&-a&0}.$$ 
We know such a matrix is diagonalizable via an orthogonal matrix. In particular, its spectrum is all real and its characteristic polynomial splits over $\mathbb{R}$.

For $x=a$, we get a rank one matrix $aI_4-A$. This means that $a$ is an eigenvalue and that the corresponding eigenspace has dimension $3$, which is also the multiplicity of $a$ in the characteristic polynomial.

There only remains one eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity $1$ to find. It suffices to take the trace: 
$$\mbox{Tr} A=0=3a+\lambda \quad\Rightarrow\quad\lambda=-3a.$$

So
$$
p_A(x)=(x-a)^3(x+3a).
$$