# Q: The determinant of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I really struggle with this problem, how do you calculate the determinant of matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, whose expression is 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 &  1&  ...& 1\\ 
 1&  2&  ...& 1\\ 
 1&  1&  2& ...\\ 
 1&  1&  ...& 2
\end{pmatrix} ?
$$

Comment: Did you try some induction?

Comment: A more general problem which can be solved by very similar methods: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644/determinant-of-a-specially-structured-matrix and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382799/a-problem-on-solving-a-determinant-equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Add all the columns to the first one then subtract the first row from the other rows. Develop now according to the first column.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Find all the nonzero eigenvalues of $A - I$ with their multiplicities and recall that commuting matrices are simultaneously triangularizable.

Comment: I don't get the simultaneously triangularizable part. Certainly one does not need that rather deep fact to see that the eigenvalues (with algebraic multiplicities) of $A-I$ are obtained from those of $A$ by subtracting $1$ from each eigenvalue?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Oh you're right, I don't know why I used this reasoning. Thank you.