# Determinant of nXn matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I know this was already asked before here:
[Q: The determinant of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660684/q-the-determinant-of-a-nxn-matrix)

But I still did not manage to solve this with the method he suggested.
I tried adding all the columns to the first one (c2+c1, c3+c1.... c n + c1) 
And then I subtracted the rows from the first one (r2-r1...r3-r1...r n -r1)
But after I developed according to the first column I got stuck.

Can anyone guide me or give me an example that shows how to calculate the determinant (step by step)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What matrix do you have after adding the columns and subtracting the rows?

Comment: Remember that $\text{det}(a_1|\cdots |a_i + \lambda a_j |\cdots a_n)= \text{det}(a_1|\cdots |a_i  |\cdots a_n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as written there: add columns $\;2,3,...,n\;$ to column $\;1\;$ and then substract rows $\;2,3,...,n\;$ from first one:

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&1&1&\ldots&1\\
1&2&1&\ldots&1\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
1&1&1&\ldots&2\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}n+1&1&\ldots&1&1\\
n+1&2&1&\ldots&1\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
n+1&1&1&\ldots&2\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}n+1&1&\ldots&1&1\\
0&1&0&\ldots&0\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&0&\ldots&1\end{pmatrix}$$

But now you have an upper triangular matrix whose determinant's calculation is trivial.

Comment: Now I see where was my mistake. I feel a bit silly asking, but I really didn't quite understand - when you add rows 2,3...n to column 1, I understand why the first number at the first column is n+1. But why do the other numbers at column 1 become n+1? 
The second number at the 1st column is 1, so you add the numbers of column 2,3,4...n it should be 1+2+(1)^n-1 no? What am I missing?

Comment: @EranDavid Take the second row, for example: we add to the first entry all the other entries in that row, getting $$1+2+\overbrace{1+\ldots +1}^{n-2\;\text{times}}=1+2+n-2=n+1$$ and similarly with the other first entries in each row.

Comment: That's what I was missing... I understand now. 
Thank you so much for the explanation!