# find the determinant of the following matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the determinant of the following matrix:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&...&0\\1&...&0&1\\.&.&.&.\\0&1&...&1\end{bmatrix}$$

The size is $n\times n$ and the entries are ones except for zeros on the anti-diagonal.

My answer is $(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$ but I am not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure what the general entry pattern is; is it just zeros on the off diagonal and ones elsewhere?

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out the pattern! Is it all ones except the "anti-diagonal"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference);  I don't understand your formula.

Comment: yes @Dave it just zeros on the off diagonal and ones elsewhere

Comment: For n=3 I get $-2$. For n=4, I get $-3$ so I think your conjecture does not hold

Comment: I'm going to edit the Question, since you agree that "main diagonal" does not describe the location of the zero entries.  The phrase "anti-diagonal" is more usual.  Feel free to rollback my edit if you think it unsuitable, and please give some indication of what you've already done to solve the problem (e.g. some small examples or search for similar problems).

Comment: @hardmath I'm used to hearing "minor diagonal".

Comment: Note that, after $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ row swaps, we get $\det(A)=(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\det(J-I)$ where $J$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of all $1$'s and $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix (so this just swaps the zeros to be on the main diagonal; maybe this makes it easier to visualize).

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in my comment, we have $$\det(A)=(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\det(J-I)$$ where $J$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of all $1$'s and $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Now you can use (for instance) [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903760/what-is-the-determinant-value-of-j-i-if-i-is-identity-matrix-and-j-1-101) to finish (the answer in this one provides the solution for $n=101$, but I think it is clear how to generalize from the answer).

> The final answer can take the form $$\det(A)=(-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^{n+1}(n-1).$$

Comment: +1 Swapping rows to get $J-I$ is a clever idea.

Answer (score 0):

The determinant of $A$ is given by $(-1)^{\frac{2n+1+(-1)^{n+1}}{4}+1}(n-1)$ for $n>1$.

When $n=2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...$ then the determinant is $1,-2,-3,4,5,-6,-7,8,9,...$ respectively.

The part $(-1)^{\frac{2n+1+(-1)^{n+1}}{4}+1}$ tells us that the sign alternates every two terms.

Comment: The answer should make sence

Comment: @T.fizuty I have edited my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: The sign is $+1$ when $n\equiv1,2\pmod{}4$ and $-1$ when $n\equiv0,3\pmod{4}$.  Do you have a general proof, or just a few examples?

Comment: @saulspatz consider the numerator that appears in the exponent, for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...$, then when that numerator is divided by $4$, then we get $1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,...$. The $+1$ is just to adjust the sign when $(-1)$ is raised to that power. By finite mathematical induction, it is easy to prove. You can try it.