# Inverse of matrix of ones minus identity matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

### What is the solution for

$$A^{-1}(n) = (\mathbf{1}_{n} - I_{n})^{-1},$$
where $\mathbf{1}_{n}$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of ones and $I_{n}$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

#### Numerical Examples Suggest

$$
A^{-1}(n) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-n+2}{n-1} & \frac{1}{n-1} & \frac{1}{n-1} & ... \\
\frac{1}{n-1} & \frac{-n+2}{n-1} & \frac{1}{n-1} & ... \\
\frac{1}{n-1} & \frac{1}{n-1} & \frac{-n+2}{n-1} & ... \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \frac{-n+2}{n-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

#### For similar questions on determinants, see

[How to calculate the determinant of all-ones matrix minus the identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84206)

[Why is the determinant of the all one matrix minus the identity matrix n-1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392577)

[How to calculate the determinant of all-ones matrix minus the identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84206)

[Determinant of a matrix with diagonal entries $a$ and off-diagonal entries $b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86644)

[Determinant of a specific circulant matrix, $A_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81016)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct application of the [Sherman–Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula)

$$
(A+uv^{T})^{-1}=A^{-1}-{A^{-1}uv^{T}A^{-1} \over 1+v^{T}A^{-1}u}
$$

with $A=-I_n$ (where $I_n$ is the identity matrix), $v=w=\mathbf{1_1}$ (vectors filled with $1$)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very elementary approach : by direct computation, $A$ satisfies $$A^2 =(n-2)A + (n-1)I_n$$

One deduces that $$A \times \left[\dfrac{1}{n-1}\Big(A + (2-n)I_n \Big) \right] = I_n,$$ and therefore, $A$ is invertible and $$\boxed{A^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{n-1}\left(A + (2-n)I_n \right)}$$