# Evaluate $\det A$ for an $n \times n$ matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ when ~~

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Evaluate $\det A$ for an $n\times n$ matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ when

(1) $a_{ij}= 1$ if $i\ne j$, $a_{ij}=0$ if $i=j$

(2) $a_{ij} = i+2j$

---

I study linear algebra alone. I don't have a man asking math questions around me :(
I'm a little hazy on this problem. First I use cofactor expansion.
However I am very confusing about $n \times n$ matrix. Mealwhile I think use Math induction. Can you help me??

Comment: For the first one, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84206/how-to-calculate-the-following-determinants-all-ones-minus-i.

Comment: You can only use induction if you already have the expression for the determinant, to prove that it holds in general. You can't use induction to find the expression itself. If you are able to derive the expression, induction won't be necessary anymore.

Comment: Oh, I can't find out a while ago. I'm not used to this website. Thank you so much :)

Comment: hmm, so i can't use induction..  thank you for your help

Comment: The second part is easy if you notice that the rows and columns of the matrix for $n>2$ are arithmetic progressions. For $n>2$, perform the operations $R_n\to R_n-R_{n-1}$ and $R_{n-1}\to R_{n-1}-R_{n-2}$ in that order, getting two identical rows. For $n=1,2$, the determinant is non-zero and can be calculated separately.

Comment: thanks so much :) I will try it!