# Characteristic polynomial of a hollow matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

I'm searching a way to calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Is it smarter to analyze the difference ${\bf J} - {\bf I}_{n \times n}$, where $\bf J$ is the matrix full with ones and ${\bf I}_{n \times n}$ the identity matrix?

Comment: Yes indeed! The eigenvalues of $A+cI$ are always $c$ plus the eigenvalues of $A$ (with the same eigenvectors); and here the eigenvalues of $J$ are easy to determine.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/904926/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84206/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4214740/339790)